# Selecting some columns from a already defined range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new into VBA for excel and I was trying to select some columns within a range (that is working in a loop). Then I want to merge these columns. I've coded like that for now

```
For l = 2 To 8
Worksheets("SdB pg1").Range(Geo1).Columns(l).MergeCells = True
Next l`
```

Geo1 is a Range variable

l is an integer variable

But I Want to make it run just for columns 2 and 3 then pick columns 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 together and then merge. I've already tried "And", "&", Columns("K:O") with no success. 
If possible, i don't want to create new variables, just work directly with the range and avoiding ".select".
Hope any of you could help.

Comment: Showing an image of before and after of some example data of what you're trying to 'merge' would be very helpful.

Comment: They're empty cells. The code I wrote down was for formatting borders and cells ranges in an output table based on input data for defining the ranges. The answer down here nailed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim l As Long
    Dim Geo1 As Range

    Set Geo1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sdb pg1").Range("A1:H5")

    Geo1.Columns(2).Resize(, 2).MergeCells = True
    Geo1.Columns(4).Resize(, 5).MergeCells = True

End Sub
```

I've added the borders manually:
[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. The part that interested me was the one that merged the cells 5 to 8. 2 and 3 should be one at a time as they already was.